# How to use Zend DB to add value to existing value in table

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db

I would like to do the follow query in Zend DB style. Basically i want to add 1000 to the value in my table where id = 1.

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `some_table` SET `value` = `value` + 1000 WHERE `id` = 1");
```

This is my Zend query, but it does not work

```
$data= array('value' => 'value'+1000);
$this->dbo->update('some_table', $data, $this->dbo->quoteInto('id = ?','1'));
```

Advice appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
$data = array('value' => new Zend_Db_Expr('value + 1000'));
$this->dbo->update('some_table', $data, $this->dbo->quoteInto('id = ?', 1);
```

You need to use [`Zend_Db_Expr`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.select.html#zend.db.select.building.columns-expr) so that `Zend_Db` doesn't try to quote that value or apply any transformations to it.